# How do I implement a real-time data push mechanism C# to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, real-time

I have to develop an architecture where a C# program on a windows server sends out market (stock) data once a second to over 1000 web clients which are in jQuery (on a Linux box, LAMP stack).  Some users may require dedicated channels.

How can I implement a reliable, scalable, and enterprise level solution myself without using third party paid services such as Pusher or PubNub?

The data channels have to be secure (SSL).

Thanks.

Comment: Use `SignalR`..

Comment: Thanks, is that very intensive for the windows server that's sending out the messages if the scale becomes larger?

Comment: I don't think so, as it has been specifically designed for providing **real-time web functionality to applications**.. Well you might want to look other constraints too in some case..

Comment: what other constraints would I have to consider in this development?

Comment: As of your requirements mentioned in the question, I cannot specifically point to any constraints and the above mentioned technology suits your requirement. You might need to follow trial and error approach for detailed result..